# How to place the box shadow of sibling elements behind both?

Tags: html, css

I have a flex container with multiple children, which all have separate `box-shadow`s. They unfortunately overlap each other, even though they have the same `z-index`.

Is there anything I can do about this?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  background-color: white;
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

> Note: The items should have separate shadows, so placing the shadow on the container won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `z-index` from the actual element and add a `:before` pseudo-element, where the actual shadow and `z-index: -1` will be applied.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: auto; /* <- needs to be unset, or auto */
}

/* add shadow to :before */
.item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```